# how to configure session time out in spring acegi framework?

Tags: time, session-timeout, spring-security

We are using acegi security for my spring application.
Can you please help how to make user to session time out by 5 mins and go back to login screen?
I tried to configure `session-timeout` in web.xml. But it is not working.
Thank you for your help and time.

---

I realized that i need to keep `5 min = 300000 mill secconds` on expiring tickets in acegi security configuration xml.

Now i have another questions that  how to redirect to application home page on login. Currently it is trying to go to the page where it previously logged out. But i want to make it as home page on what ever condition.
Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Normally if i post question, within 1 hour i will get some answers. But this time why i am not getting any thing? Is my question is not understandable? I am looking forward this. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing following expiration policy, we can make session log out within time

```
<bean
        id="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy"
        class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.MultiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy">
          <constructor-arg
            index="0"
            value="1" />
         <constructor-arg
            index="1"
            value="600000" />
    </bean>
```

[Cas expiration policies](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Ticket+Expiration+Policy) gives more information.

To redirect to login page use following:

```
<property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
```

in `casProcessingFilter` bean configuration

Answer (score 3):

to get forwared to a specific url after a timeout (defined in the web.xml), you may use

```
  <http>
    ...
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/sessionTimeout.htm" />
  </http>
```

[Session Management docu](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-mgmt)